# How to check for the existence of an element in a Liquid array (Shopify) without using join

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to check for array values in an array created from a "split". Is there a way to do it without doing the following:

```
{%- assign blog_tags_string = blogs.news.all_tags | join ' ' -%}

{%- if blog_tags_string contains blog_title -%}
    {%- assign is_tag_page = true -%}
{%- else -%}
    {%- assign is_tag_page = false -%}
{%- endif -%}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/operators/#contains) we can see that :

> `contains` can also check for the presence of a string in an array of strings.

So, no `join` is necessary, and this will do the job.

```
{%- if blogs.news.all_tags contains blog_title -%}
...
```

Comment: AWESOME! I wasn't aware of this documentation. You've answered my question and steered me to a great resource. Thanks!